# PHP/mysql update row failure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in index.php page with columns and contact information, and extra column to edit the information of user in a specific row in that row I have this code:

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

in edit.php page, I am trying to update that information but it does not work!it echo's updated successfully but in the database the value stays the same, can anyone please explain whats wrong with my code here it is:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])){  $id=$_GET['id']; 
    include('my_connection.php'); 

   $newfname = $_POST['newfname'];
   $newlname = $_POST['newlname'];
   $newtelephone = $_POST['newtelephone'];
   $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
   $newaddress = $_POST['newaddress'];

if($_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newtelephone] == "" || $_POST[newemail] == "" || $_POST[newaddress] == ""){

    $false='Failed to update because some fields are Empty, please fill in all the fields';
     } 
else
    {

    $update="UPDATE `Addresses` SET firstname='$newfname', lastname='$newlname', telephone='$newtelephone', email='$newemail', address='$newaddress' WHERE userId='$userid' AND id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connect, $update) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

    $success='Updated successfully';
} }
```

Comment: `$_GET['id']` will not be set until you click on the Edit link. Looks like you are trying to combine GET and POST in a way that won't work. You should try `var_dump()` to see what values are actually getting passed.

Comment: try to var_dump the connection and the $result variable. Also see the logs if you have any problem with query

Comment: But he's getting through to the `$success = 'Updated Successfully';` which would mean that `if ( isset($_POST['update']) )` is satisfied.

Comment: can you explain further how to user var_dump() because I never used it before, I'm still a beginner can you show me the syntax? and how should I get the id at the same time I want post method?

Comment: var_dump your query $update, echo the mysqli_error, you need escape the datas. And what is $userid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Here is your problem part you can't get values from get method when you submit.
So you need to add some hidden field into your form like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Change your code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 
  $id=$_POST['id'];
```

Maybe it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `$userid`? You have it in your query, but I do not see it in your script: `WHERE userId='$userid'`

And you're mixing `$_POST` with `$_GET`. While this is technically *possible*, I'm not sure you're doing it by design as it appears you're clicking an *edit* link which passes the 'id' to the URL query string. But where are your `$_POST` values coming from? Are you somehow submitting a `form`, too? If you're simply clicking the *edit* link, as-is, then you won't be left with any `$_POST` values. So if you have a `<form>`, please post it as well. Is `echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";` part of a form?

What you'd need to do to capture all the values is create a form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="newfname" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="newlname" value="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="newtelephone" value="<?php echo $row['telephone']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="newemail" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="newaddress" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>">

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then grab the `$_POST` values like such (using [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://mysqli_real_escape_string) to avoid SQL injection):

```
$newfname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newfname']);
$newlname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newlname']);
$newtelephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newtelephone']);
$newemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newemail']);
$newaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newaddress']);
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

You need to include some methods of retrieving any errors/issues within your code. Try the following:

```
$update = "UPDATE `Addresses` SET firstname='$newfname', lastname='$newlname', telephone='$newtelephone', email='$newemail', address='$newaddress' WHERE userId='$userid' AND id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $update);

$success = 'Failed';
if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
    $success = 'Updated successfully';
else
    trigger_error( "Query: " . $update . "\n\n" . mysqli_error($connect) );
```

***Note**: this line should be throwing a `NOTICE` (not error) stating something to the effect of: `Use of undefined constant newname - assumed 'newname'`, etc. for each. [PHP Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

```
if($_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newtelephone] == "" || $_POST[newemail] == "" || $_POST[newaddress] == ""){
```

Meaning, you need to wrap the keys in quotes, like so:

```
if($_POST['newname'] == "" || $_POST['newtelephone'] == "" || $_POST['newemail'] == "" || $_POST['newaddress'] == ""){
```

Comment: When I tried to add the error retrieving it game me this error:

Notice: Query: UPDATE `Addresses` SET firstname='ee', lastname='e', telephone='eeeeeeeeeee', email='eeeeeeeeeeeee', address='eeeeeee' WHERE userId='1' AND id='' Table 'Addresses' doesn't exist in /home/h .. etc

I noticed its not getting the id value , as you see id= empty !

Comment: and yes I have a from to insert the new data into the database and from their I post the information into the database

Comment: Also says that the table `Addresses` doesn't exist. Does it exist?

Comment: Can you post the form please? We really need to see *all* relevant information/code to fully assist.

Comment: FYI, on Linux distros, MySQL table names are typically (more often than not, but dependant on the distro) cAse-SenSiTive. Are you certain that your table `Addresses` isn't `addresses`?

Comment: I wrote the name In a wrong way, now it works! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well this should work. If you're not using the $_GET['id'] intentionally and just want it passed I would suggest using POST.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{  
    $id=$_GET['id']; 
    include('my_connection.php'); 

    $newfname = $_POST['newfname'];
    $newlname = $_POST['newlname'];
    $newtelephone = $_POST['newtelephone'];
    $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
    $newaddress = $_POST['newaddress'];

    if($_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newname] == "" || $_POST[newtelephone] == "" || $_POST[newemail] == "" || $_POST[newaddress] == "")
    {
        $result='Failed to update because some fields are Empty, please fill in all the fields';
    } 
    else
    {
        $update="UPDATE `Addresses` SET firstname='".$newfname."', lastname='".$newlname."', telephone='".$newtelephone."', email='".$newemail."', address='".$newaddress."' WHERE userId='".$userid."' AND id='".$id."';";
        mysqli_select_db($connect,"dbName");
        $result=mysqli_query($connect, $update) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        $result='Updated successfully';
    } 
    echo $result;
}
```

Oh forgot define $userid